# how to show the gmap in asp.net webform on buttonclick when i enter destinations in textbox1 and textbox2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to show the gmap in asp.net webform on buttonclick when i enter destinations in textbox1 and textbox2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try Artem.GoogleMap.

Samples : http://googlemap.artembg.com/map/Default.aspx

Code and Binary : http://googlemap.codeplex.com